# Define a generic class and implement generic interface

Tags: c#, generics

I have following code

```
public interface IDummy<TType> where TType : new()
{
}

public class Dummy<TType> : IDummy<TType>
{
}
```

And compile failed, because of `Error   1   'TType' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TType' in the generic type or method 'ConsoleApplication1.IDummy<TType>'   D:\Temp\ConsoleApplication1\Dummy.cs    5   18  ConsoleApplication1`

But if I change code to

```
public interface IDummy<TType>
{
}

public class Dummy<TType> : IDummy<TType> where TType : new()
{
}
```

Then compile is successful. I have no way to define the generic type requirement at interface level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the restriction on *both* places:

```
public interface IDummy<TType> where TType : new()
{
}

public class Dummy<TType> : IDummy<TType> where TType : new()
{
}
```